# Correlations significant at individual level, but not at group level?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, biostatistics, spearman-rho

For my research I have to do correlation tests to see how different measures of animal welfare are related to each other. When i run the test using the data at individual level, it shows a weak correlation but significant in most cases. However, when I run the tests using data clustered at pen level, the correlations between the same variables show a stronger relationship but the p-value is often not significant or slightly above 0.05.
Does someone have an idea why a correlation at individual level would be significant, while at pen level it is not?

Comment: What means "I run the tests using data clustered at pen level"?

Comment: I mean that I took the averages for the values of each animal in the same pen

Answer (score 2):

See the answer at [Correlation: average observations Vs observations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350289/correlation-average-observations-vs-observations): When you correlate averages, it will tend to be stronger because averaging reduces noise/variance.

But, since the number of pens (groups) will be smaller (maybe much!) than number of individuals, the higher correlations might not be significant.

Some other relevant posts:

- [Correlation on mean values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116713/correlation-on-mean-values)
- [Should I draw the conclusions from average or individual data? Is this approach using Pearson CC correct?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285869/should-i-draw-the-conclusions-from-average-or-individual-data-is-this-approach)